# Looking for good book/sefer on Kilayim of clothing

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, shaatnez

I'm looking for a few good seforim on Hilchos Kilayim of clothing. I would love a sefer that works through the Shulchan Aruch as well as a sefer that deals with the Halachic issues of kilayim of begadim as they apply to today's clothing. Hebrew or English is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two good Seforim on Shatnez.

1) Dinei Shatnez (with pictures)- Avraham Chaim Edes

[image]

2)Hashatnez L'halacha U'lmaaseh - Rav Elchonon Cohen

[image]